# Subtract data php

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I'm trying to subtract one date on another on PHP, create a new date of 8 hours (08:00:00) and subtract it from the previous result.

I used TIMEDIFF to subtract the first two dates and then DateTime to convert it to date format.

Then I used date_create to create the 8 hours date, in order make the subtraction from the previous result.

The problem is that when I used TIMEDIFF making that last calculation, it returns me the following message:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /Users/renatoaraujo/Documents/wlib compartilhada/wlib/ponto/index.php on line 50
```

Where am I missing?

This is my code:

```
        $row = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT TIMEDIFF('".$ponto[0]."','".$ponto[1]."')");
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($row);

        $datetime = new DateTime($resultado[0]);
        $data = date_create('08:00:00');

        $row2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT TIMEDIFF('".$resultado[0]."', '".$data."'");
        $saldo_total = mysqli_fetch_array($row2);
```

Comment: Also, you're not actually using the `$datetime` anywhere?

Comment: AplineCoder, sorry, it was because I was making a few tests before posting this. The correct on the last query is "SELECT TIMEDIFF('".$datetime."', '".$data."'");

Comment: Royal BG, I saw that function here. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_create.asp

Comment: neither $datetime nor $data are strings, they both are DateTime objects. You need to convert them to string representation

Answer (score 2):

Why are you querying the database for this?  You can do everything you need with `DateTime`.

You could do this as simply as:

```
$start_time = new DateTime();
$eight_hours_before = $start_time->modify('-8 hours');
```

Or alternately you could use `DateInterval`.

```
$start_time = new DateTime();
$eight_hours = new DateInterval('P8H');
$start_time->sub($eight_hours);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it shows "Fatal error: Call to a member function modify() on a non-object". If I use date_format and pass it to a string, it shows 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string'. Any clues?

Comment: @user3596108 Can you show me exactly how you are trying to instantiate the `DateTime` class? It seems clear that the object was not instantiated for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`$data` is a `DateTime`, not a string. You need to use `date_format()` to convert it to a string:

```
$row2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT TIMEDIFF('".$resultado[0]."', '".date_format($data, 'Y-m-d H:i:s)."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a DateTime for 8 hours ago, then this can be done directly in the [\DateTime constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). Something like this:-

```
$eightHoursAgo = new \DateTime('- 8 hours');
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/mTQ1J)